# Convert mono-label Classifier into multi-label classifier

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, image-recognition, multiclass-classification

*Hi guys !*

To resume my problem : I have a simple image classifier (2conv + 2fc) which is doing a great job on my dataset (95% acc) . However i was ask to made it a multi-label classifier which was done by changing :

```
self.cost  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
            labels=self.labels,
            logits=self.out) )
```

into :

```
self.cost  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits (
                labels=self.labels,
                logits=self.out) )
```

With the same learning rate I have (what i think is) an overfitting causing the test output to be 0 with all the inputs (which is really strange) . And with a lower learning rate i have a really poor accuracy on both test and train.

Is my method wrong ? Or should i change some hyperparameters ?
Thanks !

**EDIT**

After some test I can give more detail about my problem .

Im using differents accuracy formulas for both classifiers, for multi-class classification:

```
tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.net.labels, 1), tf.argmax(self.net.out, 1))
```

for multi-label classification:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(self.net.output), tf.round(self.net.labels))
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.net.labels, 1), tf.argmax(self.net.out, 1))
self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

When i'm using the first formula with both models they all give me good results.

However the second formula with the multi-label classifier give terrible results . And this is because the second model learn to maximise the most likely output , but the value of the maximum output is too low , always being below 0.5 .

Answer (score 0):

Is it binary classification problem? *Sigmoid* is applicable in binary classification problems only.

*Softmax* and *Sigmoid* theoretically are same but practically softmax gives at maximum 1% better accuracy. Since your result has dropped from 95% which indicates some other problem with the way you provide labels to the network or may be the problem with the network itself.

Verify labels are in the right format or any inherent issue with the network. Also, verify with sigmoid there must be *one* output otherwise the number of outputs is the number of classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I edit the post . I hope this give you a better understanding of the problem . And by the way my labels are good

Comment: How many classes do you have? 
What do you mean by multi-label?

Comment: I'm testing on 10 classes right now .And multi-label mean that my outputs are non exclusive . For a given example the output could be the class n°1 and the class n°5 in the same time .